# Is there a way to speed up Delphi Android 64-bit debugging?

Tags: android, delphi, 64-bit

I am noticing that Delphi Android targeting 32-bit debug is so much faster than targeting 64-bit debug.  I'm curious why this is and how I can fix it, if possible?

Comment: Try using the `/fast_debugging` command line switch for the IDE. Failing that, submit a QP report to Embarcadero.

Comment: Delphi 32bit debuger is GDB, 64bit debugger is LLDB. Except filing bug report and hoping Embarcadero has room for improving LLDB debugging speed there is nothing you can do at the moment. Unless you are debugging code that depends on bitness, I suggest you use 32bit debugger for the time being.

Comment: Consolidation of LLDB debugging is on the [roadmap in mid-2020](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/august-2019-delphi-android-beta-plans-august-roadmap-update).